# Magento 2 Order / Shipment Emails From Address Suddenly Apache / apache@localhost

Tags: magento2, email

I have recently updated to 2.2.4 and made a few minor changes however have just noticed that **order emails** are now sending with the **wrong from address** and is not set as per settings in `Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses` as I believe normally sets this.

Header shows like below:

```
From: Apache <apache@server.co.uk>
Return-Path: apache@server.co.uk
```

However previous headers and the current live site set this correctly and am unsure why this has suddenly started. Emails sent from forgotten passwords works fine and from what I can tell this is only effecting the order and shipment emails.

I have tried debugged this through about a maze of files all the way down to `Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilderByStore` and everything seems fine back to there.

The `$this->message->setFrom($result['email'], $result['name']);` seems to be correct and `$result['email']` and `$result['name']` are correct at this stage however the from address is not set.

`$this->message` uses the `magento\Framework\Mail\Message` class which just extends `Zend_Mail` for the setting of the from address so am unsure what could go wrong at this stage considering the variables sent to the function look fine.

Forgotten password however does not seem to use the TransportBuilderByStore so will try and figure out what is different for forgotten password emails.

I can see a similar issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6146 however this is very old. Has anyone else had an issue with this recently since updating? Why would this go wrong and how can I fix?

For now my best bet is just setting the from address via vhosts for each of the multi stores like below however would like to find out why this is happening?

```
php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -fsales@domain.co.uk  -F 'Sales Department <sales@domain.co.uk>' -t
```

Comment: Refer this issue all explanations are there, hope this will help you.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952

Comment: Wow swear i've scoured github for this issue and couldn't find. Thanks so much i'll take a read.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. That was perfect thanks for that all fixed! Hopefully they sort it for 2.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find solution from magento patch website. Kindly go through and  you can fixed this issue

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024855431-Order-email-sent-from-the-server-email-address

Here is best result