# Use my domain for sales emails instead of my hosting domain

Tags: magento2, email

All my automated sales emails (like order confirmation, shipment...etc ) are sent from username@myhostingdomain.com,

I want emails to be sent from my Magento domain exemple: sales@mydomain.com

thank You.

Comment: What's your email setup in magento backend?

Comment: what you mean by email setup explain please ? , in Magento backend all emails are set to @mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

You can configure them at :

> Store > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email

Comment: in Magento backend all emails are set to @mydomain.com but emails are sent from my hosting domain

Comment: Please have a check with server settings in that case, sometimes it being reset from there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like more people have this problem:

Temp solution add this to your php.ini  (I checked this  now and its works for me)

```
sendmail_path= "/usr/sbin/sendmail -f yoursale@domain.com -F 'Your SHOP <yoursale@domain.com>' -t
```

or disable amazon pay.

More:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952

[Magento 2 Order / Shipment Emails From Address Suddenly Apache / apache@localhost](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228099/magento-2-order-shipment-emails-from-address-suddenly-apache-apachelocalhos)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried this but still not working,