# Sales orders being sent from sever host

Tags: order-email

Running 2.2.7 Community Edition all my emails, besides new account, are being sent by my sever user user@server.domain.com instead of what I have set in email address configuration. This issue appeared without changing any email settings that I know of. Possibly after an update though? Maybe I'm missing a setting?

Comment: Some issue here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243314/use-my-domain-for-sales-emails-instead-of-my-hosting-domain

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. For some reason I was thinking it was a different issue since I was on a later version than others. I was able to fix it by adding this in my php.ini file under [mail function]
sendmail_path= "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f username@domain.com -F username"